# pass image from day to night with python PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

i've some complication with pass a image from day to night in python.

this is my code:

```
enter code here 
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
# convierte una imagen tipo Imagen (de la libreria PIL) en una matriz(ETD) con la informacion RGB de la imagen
def convertirImgMatrixRGB(img):
    return np.array(img.convert("RGB"))
# convierte una imagen tipo Imagen (de la libreria PIL) a imagen en Negativo
# procedimiento : multiplica por base 255 cada casilla de la matriz RGB para convertir la imagen en negativo

def PasarDiaNoche(img):
    arrImg = convertirImgMatrixRGB(img)
    for i in range(img.size[1]):
        for j in range(img.size[0]):
            arrImg[i][j][0] = arrImg[i][j][0] * 0.1 #rojo
            arrImg[i][j][1] = arrImg[i][j][2] * 0.2 #verde
            arrImg[i][j][2] = arrImg[i][j][2] *1.7 #azul
    imgSepia = Image.fromarray(arrImg)
    return imgSepia
def main():
    img=Image.open("paisaje2.jpg")
    arrImg = convertirImgMatrixRGB(img)
    #r, g, b = img.getpixel((100, 100))
    #print r,g,b
    imgNegativa=PasarDiaNoche(img)
    imgNegativa.save("paisajeNoche.jpg") #guarda la imagen negativo
main()
```

first, i have to pass to array an image for work pixel by pixel, later pass from day to night

this are my results:

original : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxLtG.jpg

night: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cblzD.jpg

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work about the code you have?

Comment: What is the converted value of the blue channel if it starts at 200? Does it become 340? What does Image.fromarray() do with a channel value > 255?

Comment: you look images ?? in the mountain are some wrong things..

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
        arrImg[i][j][2] = arrImg[i][j][2] *1.7 #azul
```

causes a problem, because the data type of `arrImg` is probably unsigned 8 bit, and this multiplication causes the values to overflow.  For example, in the following, `a` is a numpy array of 8 bit unsigned integers, with a single value:

```
In [6]: a
Out[6]: array([240], dtype=uint8)
```

If we attempt to multiply that by 1.7 and store the result back in `a`...

```
In [7]: a[0] = a[0] * 1.7
```

we get the wrong value (note that 408 modulo 256 is 152):

```
In [8]: a
Out[8]: array([152], dtype=uint8)
```

You can fix this by doing the calculation with floating point values, and convert back to 8 bit afterwards, if necessary.

You can also get rid of those loops.  You can accomplish the calculation, using numpy's "broadcasting" capability, with a single line.  This line can also be written so that the integer values are cast up to floating point.  Here's an example.

I saved the image as 'view.jpg', and I'll use `scipy.misc.imread` to read it into a numpy array called `img`:

```
In [46]: from scipy.misc import imread

In [47]: img = imread('view.jpg')
```

Take a look at some of the attributes of `img`:

```
In [48]: img.shape
Out[48]: (488, 650, 3)

In [49]: img.dtype
Out[49]: dtype('uint8')
```

This single line creates a new array, in which the red, green and blue channels have been multiplied by 0.1, 0.2 and 1.7, respectively.  (This is an example of numpy's "broadcasting" ability.)  Because the second multiplicand is a floating point array, the result is also a floating point array.

```
In [50]: arr = img * np.array([0.1, 0.2, 1.7])
```

Here are the shape and data type of `arr`:

```
In [51]: arr.shape
Out[51]: (488, 650, 3)

In [52]: arr.dtype
Out[52]: dtype('float64')

In [53]: arr.max()
Out[53]: 433.5
```

The following rescales `arr` so that the maximum value is 255.0, and then casts it to an array of 8 bit unsigned integers.

```
In [54]: img2 = (255*arr/arr.max()).astype(np.uint8)

In [55]: img2.dtype
Out[55]: dtype('uint8')

In [56]: img2.max()
Out[56]: 255
```

Here is `img2`:

[image: night view]